# replace config params and swap the lines in config.yml

Tags: linux, shell

I have config.yml file which has the lines like below.

```
- uri: "https://localhost1/status"
  name: "INST1"
  
- uri: "https://loclahost2/status"
  name: "INST2"

- uri: "https://localhost3/status"
  name: "INST3"
```

I need to change these config entry's like below format..

```
- Displayname: "INST1"
  uri: "https://localhost1/status"
  
- Displayname: "INST2"
  uri: "https://loclahost2/status"

- Displayname: "INST3"
  uri: "https://localhost3/status"
```

I have tried with sed/awk command to replace the string from `name` to -`Displayname` but not sure how to swap the lines as per expected format. Also tried copying the whole content in a tmp file and read 2 lines from file and replace the config values as per the config. Is there any easiest way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/swap-every-2-lines-in-file.html?m=1) for swapping lines easily in files using bash.

For replacing 'name' with 'Displayname', run
`sed - i 's/name/Displayname/g' config.yml`

Answer (score 0):

This code will resolve your issue:

```
var1=($(grep name config-yml|sed 's/name://g'))
var2=($(grep uri config-yml|sed 's/- uri://g'))
for ((i=0;i<${#var1[@]};i++))
do
        echo "- Displayname: "${var1[$i]}
        echo "  uri: "${var2[$i]}
        echo 
done
```